# Modifying Property Values in Typescript Decorator

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I have class level variable in an Angular Service. I need to prepend some value to the variables value via decorators. How can I achieve?

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceName{

  @Service(MicroService.NAME)
  apiURL='api/login'; 

}
```

The above code should prepend MicroService.NAME to apiURL.
if the value of MicroService.NAME is 'authService' then the value 
of apiURL must be changed to 'authService/api/login'.

If the above is achieved then I can replace the Micro Service name with its url in the Http Interceptor.(http://my.ip:port/api/login)

I am new to decorators. I could not find a proper solution searching the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import "reflect-metadata";

const enum MicroService {
  NAME = "microserviceName/"
}

function Service(prefix: string): PropertyDecorator {
  return (target, key): void => {
    let original = target[key];
    Reflect.deleteProperty(target, key);
    Reflect.defineProperty(target, key, {
      get: () => original,
      set: newVal => {
        original = `${prefix}${newVal}`;
      },
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    });
  };
}

export class MyClass {
  @Service(MicroService.NAME)
  public foo: string = "hello";

  public exec(): string {
    return this.foo;
  }
}

const c = new MyClass();

console.log(c.foo); // - prints: microserviceName/hello

c.foo = "test";

console.log(c.foo); // - prints: microserviceName/test
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Great answer

Comment: is my approach to redirect requests to different microservices a good one ?

Comment: Depends on the logic behind it. If it's for balancing load, no. But if it's based on another condition maybe. If above answers your original question please accept it and open another question for your redirection question.

Comment: Hi! Why do you define the `get` in the property descriptor as. `() => original`? Shouldn't it return the modified value?